# Save use of Ubuntu 18.04 and above via controlling user privileges?

Tags: 18.04, security, users

Sometime back, I had read articles advising Ubuntu users to use Standard User privilege account to do their daily work instead of using Administrator privileges, as the former approach avoids allowing the rest of the system from being infected in the event of a computer virus infection or hacker attack. **May I know if this advice still applies to current generation of Ubuntu systems like 18.04 and above?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May I know if this advice still applies to current generation of Ubuntu systems like 18.04 and above?

Yes and always will. In Linux/Ubuntu tasks are divided into 2 parts:

- system maintenance
- desktop usage

The 1st is done through an admin account. There are 2 concepts: "root" and "sudo". The advantage of the last one is that it can be logged what the admin user was that did something. The 1st concept will always log as "root".

The 2nd is what a normal user does. That normal user does not need to be the admin. It is common to have more users use a system. Think about a family computer: Mom is the admin, dad and the children are regular users. Mom installs software and sets the machine up. Dad and the kids have to abide by what mom installed. So if mom does not want dad to play games she can enforce it.

In theory the best practice is for mom to have another account that she uses as a user so different from her admin. Not a lot of people will do that though: mom would be required to log in and out and in. I myself am a single user on my machine so I use 1 account with a decent (but not to long to be annoying ;)) password.

That makes for TWO walls an attacker needs to break:

- First: an attacker needs to know user name and user password and needs to know a method to access that system (a zero day exploit for instance) to be able to break into a users system. That will let the attacker mess with a users home.
- Secondly: If that user is not the admin to really wreck a system the attacker then needs to know the admin name and the password for the admin.

And then it comes down to one simple fact: hackers will always target the weakest operating system if all they want is to wreck havoc. And that clearly (still unfortunately) is Windows. The second target for hackers it to obtain data: credit cards, mail addresses, logins and passwords to game servers. We desktop users do not tend to have those.

... so Ubuntu users are not really a target for hackers.

Comment: Thanks. In your family example, should the Mom also create an account with a standard user privilege to perform her daily work and use the administrator account only for system maintenance?  That is, the Mom should finally have two accounts?

Comment: In theory that would be the best option but is also annoying so most won't do that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it still stands, the [Ubuntu documentation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/user-management.html) for user management begins with the answer to your question. You can [check it out](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/user-management.html)